# How to use first line with id attribute?

Tags: html, css, attributes, uppercase

I need to set the font size to 22 pixels. Also, for the first paragraph that is also a direct child of the leftsection id, display the first line of the paragraph in uppercase.

I have a problem on the 2nd part, that the font cannot be changed to uppercase, anything wrong?

```
#leftsection > p{font-size:22px;
}

#leftsection > p:first-of-type:first-line{text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Comment: found it chrome and opera is not working well with first-line, but it does work well with IE.

Comment: That should definitely work. You'll have to show your HTML.

Comment: Thanks all, it works on IE only.

Comment: And Mozilla. Don't forget Mozilla. [Here, a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/uRK9T/). Also, it does work in Opera. (The real one, Presto-based. Later Webkit-based versions are a big step backwards in terms of functionality.)